# A base for the space of class functions

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group. A class function of $G$ is a function $f:G\to\Bbb{C}$ such that $f(ghg^{-1})=f(h)$ for every $g,h\in G$. Let $H$ be the set of all class functions of $G$.

$a,b\in G$ are said to be conjugated if $a = gbg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$. This is an equivalence relation on $G$ and the equivalence classes of this relation are called conjugation classes.

Let $Y$ be the set of all conjugation classes of $G$. I need to show that the family $B = (f_y)_{y\in Y}$ given by

$f_y(g) = 1$ if $g\in y$ and $f_y(g) = 0$ otherwise

is a base for $H$.

I already shown that they are l.i. To show that they generate $H$, I could only think that if $f:G\to\Bbb{C}$ is a class function then $f(g) = \sum_{y\in Y}f(g)f_y(g)$, but this doesn't quite is a linear combination of the vectors of $B$. Can someone give an ideia on this? I have already studied some group representations and characters of representations, so you can use elementary results about this.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to say that if $f : G \to \mathbb C$ is a class function, then
$$ f(g) = \sum_{y \in Y} f(g_y) f_y (g),$$
where for each conjugacy class $y \in Y$, $g_y$ is an element in $y$. (This expression is independent of our choice of the element $g_y$ in the conjugacy class $y \in Y$, since if $g'_y$ is some other element in $y$, then $f(g_y) = f(g'_y)$, since $f$ is a class function.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the conjugacy classes $y_1,...,y_r$ and let $g_1,...,g_r$ be any representatives. Then we have $f=\sum_{i=1}^r f(g_i)f_{y_i}$ for every class function $f$. Indeed, take $g\in G$ and suppose it belongs to the class $y_j$. Then:

$\sum_{i=1}^r f(g_i)f_{y_i}(g)=f(g_j)=f(g)$

**Edit:** Actually, there is a very nice notation for functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$. If $f(g)=\alpha_g$ for all $g\in G$ then we may write $f=\sum_{g\in G}\alpha_g g$, these are "formal sums". So with this notation the class functions are the sums where each two conjugate elements have the same coefficient. Now the statement becomes more intuitive, it is just $f=\sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{g\in y_i}\lambda_i g=\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_i(\sum_{g\in y_i} g)$. Really looks like we do a typical sum operation.